# PHP cant add file to database

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder why it doesn't add the file to the database? it only displays this on screen:

array(0) {

}

photos:1)https://ibb.co/bXM1x5v 2)https://ibb.co/87gBhgL

please someone helpme
thank u all in advance.

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't save your images to the database. Save the file in the directory, change its name to a unique one and save the file name in the database.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not try to add a file to the database, it's not recommended, you should save the name in the DB and save the file in the cloud/server.

Second, in your $pdo->exec the value for the image field is empty
`Values('$title','','$description','$price'");`

It will never save anything but an empty string.